# How to create a unified unix-timestamp both on iOS and Python?

Tags: python, ios, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am developing an iOS application that needs to sync with a Python based REST service on GAE.

In the python backend I create my timestamps like this:

```
def create_timestamp(date):
    midnight = datetime.time(0)
    date_midnight_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date.date(), midnight)
    return calendar.timegm(date_midnight_time.utctimetuple())
```

I pass in the function above `datetime.datetime.today()`. This would return for 27 Oct 2013 00:00:00 the value `1382832000`.

On iOS there is a buildin function for that:

nextDate is set to today's date a bit complicated due an algorithm:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

[components setDay:27];
NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

`[nextDate timeIntervalSince1970]` which returns for `2013-10-27 00:00:00 BST` the value `1382828400.000000`

There is some discrepancy though.

1. Maybe its because that Python side is UTC and iOS shows the time in BST by default and I need to address that. As of last night the British Summer time is no more, but iOS still reports BST. Thats confusing though as a NSDate object is always in UTC from my understanding....
2. Once its working, is it safe to cast the iOS double
   value to int, in order to get a round integer number similar to the Python side?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd respond, since this particular issue is something I've been looking for an answer for for a while:

The IOS timestamp you give refers to the correct midnight for GMT of that date.
The python timestamp you give refers to one hour earlier (11:00 pm on the prior day).

This took me forever to find, and it's a pretty smart way of doing it (particularly when you consider the many more circuitous options I've seen):

I tried this, and it works nicely when trying to get the timestamp for a datetime in your local zone (but..):

```
from datetime import datetime

def dt_to_timestamp(dt_object):
    """Not really a good, universal solution"""
    return eval(dt_object.strftime('%s.%f'))

dt_to_timestamp(datetime.now()) - time.time()
# -0.0002155303955078125
```

..but it fails pretty badly once it comes to looking at objects outside of your local zone:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
from pytz import utc

utc_now = datetime.now(tz=localzone).astimezone(utc)
dt_to_timestamp(utc_now) - time.time()
# 21599.98956131935, more commonly known as 21600 -- my offset from UTC
```

This is what I finally ended up with:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import utc

def dt_to_timestamp(dt_object):
    """Provides timestamp for any zone-aware datetime object.
    Works with Python 2.7 and Python 3.3, possibly others.
    Raises TypeError when naive datetime objects are given.
    """
    epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc)
    delta = dt_object - epoch
    return delta.total_seconds()

# example usage:
from tzlocal import get_localzone
ts = 1382832000
utc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts))
local_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(get_localzone())

ts == dt_to_timestamp(utc_dt) == dt_to_timestamp(local_dt)
# True
```

It handles aware datetime objects accurately, whatever their timezone.  If the caller doesn't know the timezone in order to turn it into an aware timezone, then there are other problems.  :-)  I'm of the opinion that one should always use an aware datetime objects if possible, and when not using aware datetime objects, use UTC datetimes.

I found the info for this answer (amongst a lot of other detail) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/712522).